# Set background color of jbutton on selection

Tags: arraylist, colors, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I have an arraylist of Jbuttons in a jframe, when I select a certain jbutton I need the background color of that specific jbutton to change. Any tips on how to go about this? I've tried to use Set background color but due to it being an ArrayList of buttons, it does not run.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use a map, or a forEach, to map a function onto each button checking the ID, and if it matches, then do the set colour code on that one.